# ASP MVC sb-admin 2 Bootstrap template: Panel content refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering what would be a good approach to refresh the panel content, e.g., for the tasks panel shown below.

The value (amount of tasks) is "requestable" through an API. What I want to do is to GET uri/api/tasks which returns a JSON array (list of all tasks) and update the amount of tasks.

[image]

The corresponding div in my Index.cshtml looks as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-green">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                            <div class="huge">12</div>
                            <div>New Tasks!</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#">
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Unfortunatelly I don't know where to put my API calls and how to invoke them.

Comment: you need to use signarR

Comment: thanks @janina, could you please be a little bit more specific? Do you have an example for that?

Comment: how often do you want this updating?

Comment: depends. some panles only once while the dashboard will be loaded, other panels every time the value changed. to keep things simple the only-once procedure would be enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep things simple i would use ajax and an onload function from jquery

with your c# method

```
//this will return a list of strings in json format.
public ActionResult GetData()
{
//array of string 
String[] array = {"Bob","Joe","Dave"};
 return json(array,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}

Then in the view 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: "/Controller/GetData",

        method: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {

        $.each(result,function(key,value){
        //append the dom in here for each result in the array.
        });

        },
        error: function (result) {
        }
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can `url: "/Controller/GetData"` point to any controller? I created a TaskController inside my Project Controllers directory. But it TaskController is never called!

Comment: in this case it should be then url:"/Task/GetData" notice not TaskController since the routing takes care of that for you

Comment: I used controller as a placeholder, if you have another controller say PersonController, and an actionresult of GetData it would then be, url:"/Person/GetData"

Comment: I have this inside Controllers: `public class TasksController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Tasks>();
            tasks.Add(new Tasks { amount = 4 });

            return View(tasks);
        }` and add some fake data (amount = 4) by now. I call it inside the panel by `url: "/Tasks/Index"`. Right?

Comment: Ok thanks so far! :-) one last question: the `<script>...</script>` part, where exactly do I have to put it? Do I have to create an new Task view, in /Views/Tasks of my project? This view is a cshtml file.

Comment: So, in your project you should have a 'Views' folder where all of your views are held, under there i *think* you should have areas so would be something like Views -> Tasks -> index.cshtml and you can add it in there, alternatively you should have a JS folder for site javascript, which it could go in there.