# Displaying data in a chart with ASP.NET (Razor) using a database query for chart data

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm using ASP.NET and have succeeded in displaying data from an array in a chart.

How can I display data from my database (SQL Server) in a chart using a Razor template?

Comment: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/ save properties you want to display in model, and display as @Model.propertyname

Comment: @coder771 I'm sorry sir but I don't think I understood your answer. Can u please explain how I could use that to display data from database to chart? Thanks Sir. Much Appreciated.

Comment: Are you using razor MVC?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35358679/asp-mvc-sb-admin-2-bootstrap-template-panel-content-refresh check this out.

Comment: @coder771 yes Sir, I am using razor mvc 5. I've already understood how to display the data into the chart but it is only data from an array that I defined. MY problem is that, I don't know how to display data from a query into the chart.

Comment: do you have your result in var? Can you show me how you are getting your results

Comment: I declared an array (with definite values) in my controller and yes, I call it in my View in var.

Comment: which template are you using as in chart?

Comment: i do  ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();

            var data = dashboardService.GetBarChartData(User);

            data.ToList().ForEach(rs => xValue.Add(rs.StaffName));
            data.ToList().ForEach(rs => yValue.Add(rs.StaffTicketCount));

            var chart = new Chart(600, 400)
               .AddSeries(chartType: "column",
               xValue: xValue,
               yValues: yValue)
                .Write();

            return null; to display in bootstrap admin chart

Comment: @coder771 I've seen a few tutorials, with the same syntax. But then, I am using a newer version of Chart.js so it is coded a bit differently (syntax) are you familiar with that Sir?

Comment: http://prashantjayle.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/chartjs-with-aspnet-mvc-5.html you would have to try a bit

Comment: @coder771 Sir this was exactly the same tutorial I was looking at right now. I will try to make it work. I hope I can ask you further about this. Thank you for you patience.

Comment: sure. let me know if you dont follow. it is Miss not Sir. :)

Comment: @code771 apologies Miss! I didn't know how to address you because you were a bit mysterious on your profile. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi @coder771 , I'm trying to make a JsonResult method in my controller but I'm not sure how to properly do it in MVC 5. I'm reading the link you gave me but I couldn't quite understand it just yet because I'm not sure how the Stored Proc works there. Can you please enlighten me more on this. Thank you!

Comment: sp_GetBarChartData in it is name of stored procedure

Comment: @coder771 yes miss, I get that, but what does it contain? And how was it used to get the data? Because I have a Stored Procedure and it's like this, 

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(CUSTOMER.INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID)
FROM CUSTOMER
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID

Comment: its the same fetch all data you need through stored procedure

Comment: I'm sorry for the very late response @coder771 , so the stored procedure in that tutorial returns the Month, Transaction Type and Amount? yes?

Comment: yes. you can return what you want to display

Comment: @coder771 , I see. So if I had this query, in this link http://pastie.org/10905830 , how am I gonna call the counted industry type ids as the y-axis and the industry type names as the x-axis? I'm sorry but I'm just really confused as to how to do it.

Comment: get the results in      var BarChart = new
            {
                Month = lstMonth,
                Expences = lstExpences,
                Income = lstIncome,
            }; like this from your query

Comment: call controlller method as in screenshot in the example in ajax and get results in success in ajax

Comment: This is how I draw the chart at the moment, http://pastie.org/10905853 by the way @coder771

Comment: you need to add the bit window.onload and ajax call to your controller from the example

Comment: winodw.onload is in screenshot in example

Comment: how did you get on it

Comment: @coder771 Hi there Miss! I'm really not catching up on this, I confused as to how to do it. Can u please run me through the codes? I would also really appreciate it if we could have a better medium of communication for example exchange of emails? Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117287/discussion-between-kylie-irwin-and-coder771).